# Difference between xsd:key and xsd:unique

Tags: xml, xsd

What is the difference between using xsd:unique and xsd:key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found my own answer:

It all has to do with cardinality:

xsd:key is used for (0..N) and (1..1) multiplicity.
xsd:unique is used for optional (0..1) multiplicity. This is also the reason why a the selected field in a xsd:unique can be nill.

Source of my answer:
http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/987

Answer (score 14):

**xsd:unique** does not require the field to exist for the selector. If the field exists, its value should be unique.

**xsd:key** requires the field to exist for all selector results. Every element in the selector should have a key.

Note that xsd:keyref is not a requirement for xsd:key, the xsd:key can be there withoug any xsd:keyref.

Comment: I just ran into your post... Please correct it since it is wrong to state that `only a named xsd:key can be referenced from a xsd:keyref.` See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#Identity-constraint_Definition_details): ` **{referenced key}** Required if {identity-constraint category} is keyref, forbidden otherwise. An identity-constraint definition with {identity-constraint category} equal to key or unique.`

Comment: with `xsd:unique`, you can't use `xsd:keyref` -- yes you can! See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842736/optional-key-in-xsd

Answer (score 1):

it is similar to database.

key field is like primarykey.. unique and id

unique field is not a key but it has to be unique...

Comment: Oke, but what does it add to the xsd that a key is also an "id"?

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-0-20041028/primer.html#quartelyReport.

In the example described in the link the "keyRefed" elements are the values of the number attributes of the parts of the zip of the regions and the "keyed" elements are the values of the number attribute of the part of the parts.

Unique declares that the values must be unique but can be null also, key - that they must be unique. Both types can be references by "keyRefed" elements.

Comment: I just ran into your post... Please correct it since it is wrong to state that `Keys are used with Keyrefs, restricting thus the values of "keyRefed" elements to the values actually used in "keyed" elements.` See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#Identity-constraint_Definition_details): ` **{referenced key}** Required if {identity-constraint category} is keyref, forbidden otherwise. An identity-constraint definition with {identity-constraint category} equal to key or unique.`

Answer (score 0):

xsd:key is unique AND is used for a collection of elements a key within a scope
xsd:unique is just unique within a scope.

Hope this helps...

Comment: So when i declare multiple xsd:keys on different elements, all keys defined must still be unique?

Comment: No, If you got a collection of book elements and you declared xsd:key to be the isbn attribute of the book element in the schema. Then the values of the isbn attribute should be unique. this has no influence on other elements with other keys

Comment: But xsd:unique also does this. xsd:key is also scoped. I can find no differences...?

Comment: I think the only difference is that xsd:key is not nillable, xsd:unique is...
http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#specifyingUniqueness