# Optional key in XSD

Tags: xsd, key

I've created a `key`/`keyref` on the root element in order to create document-wide uniqueness based on the specified element.

Therefore, via `.//foo/@name` every occurrence of `@name` across all instances of `foo` must be unique; likewise for `.//bar/@name`. This seems to be working fine. These are referenced by `.//foo-ref/@name-ref` and `.//bar-ref/@name-ref` respectively, also defined at the root node.

However, I've gathered that one cannot create an *optional* key, and this is presenting a bit of a problem. Semantically, by the nature of the conforming documents, a key is not required on every single instance of `foo` or `bar`. The instances of `foo-ref/@name-ref` would obviously need to target an existing `foo/@name`, but it isn't semantically invalid for a `foo` to be without a `@name`.

Is there any work-around for this? I don't like the idea of consumers having to define a key for *every* single element, when reasonably only a handful will need them.

Here's the example schema (*of course, I'm not deploying some `foobar` schema, but the structure is identical; this is just a testing schema I've been toying with*)

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="ref">
        <xs:attribute name="name-ref" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="obj">
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="foo">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="obj">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:element name="foo" type="foo" />
                        <xs:element name="bar" type="bar" />
                        <xs:element name="foo-ref" type="foo-ref" />
                        <xs:element name="bar-ref" type="bar-ref" />
                    </xs:choice>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="foo-ref">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="ref" />
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="bar">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="obj">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:element name="bar" type="bar" />
                        <xs:element name="qux" type="qux" />
                        <xs:element name="bar-ref" type="bar-ref" />
                    </xs:choice>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="bar-ref">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="ref" />
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="qux">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string" />
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="foo" type="foo" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:key name="foo">
            <xs:selector xpath=".//foo" />
            <xs:field xpath="@name" />
        </xs:key>
        <xs:key name="bar">
            <xs:selector xpath=".//bar" />
            <xs:field xpath="@name" />
        </xs:key>
        <xs:keyref name="foo-ref" refer="foo">
            <xs:selector xpath=".//foo-ref" />
            <xs:field xpath="@name-ref" />
        </xs:keyref>
        <xs:keyref name="bar-ref" refer="bar">
            <xs:selector xpath=".//bar-ref" />
            <xs:field xpath="@name-ref" />
        </xs:keyref>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

---

### Addendum

Just following up with my revisions thanks to @PetruGardea. So `unique` can be referenced by a `keyref`, who knew? (*not me apparently*)

```
<xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="foo" type="foo" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:keyref name="foo-ref" refer="foo">
        <xs:selector xpath=".//foo-ref" />
        <xs:field xpath="@name-ref" />
    </xs:keyref>
    <xs:keyref name="bar-ref" refer="bar">
        <xs:selector xpath=".//bar-ref" />
        <xs:field xpath="@name-ref" />
    </xs:keyref>
    <!--
        the use of xs:unique here, in lieu of xs:key allows for
        nullable "keys", retaining referential integrity with the
        above defined keyrefs. awesome possum.
    -->
    <xs:unique name="foo">
        <xs:selector xpath=".//foo" />
        <xs:field xpath="@name" />
    </xs:unique>
    <xs:unique name="bar">
        <xs:selector xpath=".//bar" />
        <xs:field xpath="@name" />
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [xsd:unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-key); unlike a key, its matched value is either unique or nil (nil or not present).

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="root">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="uk" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="fk" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:unique name="uq">
            <xsd:selector xpath="uk"/>
            <xsd:field xpath="@name"/>
        </xsd:unique>
        <xsd:keyref name="fk" refer="uq">
            <xsd:selector xpath="fk"/>
            <xsd:field xpath="@name"/>
        </xsd:keyref>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Sample (valid) XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <uk name="name1"/>
    <uk />
    <fk/>
    <fk name="name1"/>
</root>
```

Comment: `unique` doesn't maintain referential integrity though, does it? Can I reference a `unique` via `keyref`?

Comment: Wow. That was remarkably simple; I had somehow figured that keyrefs must reference keys. This makes life alot easier :)

Comment: @Bracketworks, actually I discovered that many helpful posts on SO mislead people in believing that unique cannot be referenced by a keyref, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253609/difference-between-xsdkey-and-xsdunique/8104006#comment22579080_8104006). Other websites imply the same...

Comment: Exactly; I had been mislead similarly (*mostly by other resources*) Thanks again, this has been bugging me for awhile (*including on previous schemas, where I can't even remember now what I used as a work-around; I probably just abandoned this factor of validation*)